# Accessing sqlite db file

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a Core Project and an Android Project and need a way to access the sqlite file when stored in the Core Project. I put it in Core/Resources and tried different Build Actions, but the file is never visible in Android Studios Device File Explorer.
If I find a way to fix this, how can I then find its path programmatically in the Core Project?

Comment: Unless you are using a root-able emulator image/device the AS Device File Explorer will not expose sandbox'd files. If you are embedding the file inside a .net assembly as a resource, you will need to "copy" it to an OS based file to use it.

Comment: as @SushiHangover says, you either need to copy it from resources to the file system, or include it in your Android project.  .NET Standard library projects do not have a mechanism to embed files